# Android applying button style to custom view

Tags: android, button, themes

I have created a custom button based on android.view.View, however, now I want application theme to be applied to my custom view. How do I go about adding the theme to my control, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

your **styles.xml** file:

```
<style name="Login.TextAppearance.ShadowText" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

your **layout.xml**

```
<CustomView
   style="@style/Login.TextAppearance.ShadowText"
/>
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply. My application is using android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar so I tried adding       style="@style/@android:style/Theme.Holo" to my custom view but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
  <CustomView
   style subtext break="@style:@/Login.TextAppearance.ShadowText"
     />
```

Also you will want to use a different parent